# Why is this little program of logicbricks not working?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, properties

[image]

Little explaining here: When the message "lap" is sent, this object should copy a property from another object "TIME" to the property "current" that's on itself. Than, as soon as "lap" is being sent again, the property sensor should check if the property "current" that is changed, because of the message, is less than the property "Text" on this object. If so, it should copy the property "current" to the property "Text" on the same object and make the object visible. There's one problem though. It works only once. The Text property is in first place set to 10000 so that it's kind of impossible to have a value higher than "Text" because it's a timer. So If I go over my finish line and the "lap" message has been sent, the "Text" property changes to the time I needed for the lap and makes the object visible successfully. But when I get a faster time, it doesn't seem to change the "Text" to a lower value.

I have been playing around with some options but I can't seem to get it done.

Someone who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable "True-Level-Triggering" on the message sensor. Also, make sure the massage is sent every tic on the object that is sending: also can be done by enabling TLT on one or all of the sensors.

True-level-Triggering makes the sensor send new positive pulse *every* logic tic that the sensor is active, rather than just once, and the a  negative when inactive. 
It can be enabled with the little three dos icon on the left of the sensor.

[image]